# How to pass the ... rest argument array to another function as an object property in flash actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a function that uses the ... rest argument as follows:

```
public function dispatchActions(... actions):void
    {
        var params:Object = new Object();       
        params.actions = actions; // I also tried casting ie. = (actions as Array)

        this.target.dispatchEvent(new ActionEvent(ActionEvent.dispatchActions, params));
    }
```

I call it using `myActionObject.dispatchActions("all");`

The problem is that when a listener receives the dispatched params object and try to access the actions array, it does nothing. If I try to trace `evt.params.actions` it traces blank and if I try to trace `evt.params.actions[0]` it traces undefined.

ex:

```
    function actionsListener(evt:ActionEvent):void
    {
        var actions:Array = (evt.params.actions) as Array; // I also tried without casting

        trace("actions", actions, "actions 0", actions[0], "action 1", actions[1]);
    }
```

This is the output: actions  actions 0 undefined actions 1 undefined

What is wrong here? I don't understand why I can't pass the ... rest argument through an object as an event parameter. How can I make this work?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your params object isn't getting sent with the event properly... I take it `ActionEvent` is your own custom event - have you checked that:

1) you are passing the `params` object in to the event constructor properly?

eg:

```
class ActionEvent extends Event{
    public var params:Object;
    public function ActionEvent(type:String, params:Object){
        super(type);
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

2) if you are redispatching the event, have you defined a `clone` function to make sure your `params` gets cloned as well?

```
 override public function clone():Event{
    return new ActionEvent(type,params);
}
```

Comment: +1. clone() was a big gotcha for me in learning AS3. Nice answer.

Comment: Well, it could very well have been that, so I still chose this answer, but actually, it was my fault. A silly problem, I was calling dispatchActions from somewhere else, and passing it no parameters, so all this time I was tracing the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
sample("as", "asd");
private function sample(... actions):void
{
    var o:Object = {};
    o.array = actions;
    sample1(o);
}
private function sample1(o:Object):void
{
    trace(o.array[1]);//traces asd
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just do this:

```
sample("as", "asd");
private function sample(... actions):void
{
    sample1(actions);
}
private function sample1(o:Array):void
{
    trace(o[1]);//traces asd
}
```